# enable a textbox when check a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I try using a jquery to enable a textbox when checked a checkbox.
[my page](http://sushiant.com/%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%A7/)
jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#isNews').change(function(){
    $("#newsSource").prop("disabled",false);
});
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isNews" name="isNews">If you want send news:
</label>
<label for="newsSource" class="ilable">news source</label>
<input id="newsSource" name="newsSource" class="input-xlarge" disabled="" type="text" placeholder="news source">
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change to

```
$('#isNews').change(function(){
   $("#newsSource").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Zr75/)

Comment: It didn't work. can you see my page? please

Comment: @Ehsan You need to use the `change` event as given `$('#isNews').change(function(){
   $("#newsSource").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});`

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the error related to non-inclusion of jQuery, change your code to this:

```
$('#isNews').change(function () {
    $("#newsSource").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak Arabic, but you're including jQuery *after* the rest of all of your scripts.  You need to include jQuery *first*.

You're getting "Undefined variable $" in the console.  Always pay attention to the console.

Comment: +1!!!! you are always fast...:):)

Comment: I put jquery in header and delete it from footer but it don't work

Comment: @Ehsan you also removed the `.change` event for some reason

Answer (score 0):

the error you have there is

```
$ is not defined
```

so you probabaly havn't loaded jquery.. :)

add this in  your `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I put jquery in head but it don't work yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is your correct code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#isNews').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
       $("#newsSource").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
       $("#newsSource").atte("disabled" , "disabled");
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I opened the link given by you. in your page source the problem is you are including jquery after the the jquery code. Try adding it before the document.ready code.

Comment: I include jquery in header but problem isn't solved